# How do i add only three items in a list flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, gridview, grid, flutter-layout

I am adding items in my list and then displaying it in a grid view.
I am selecting photos from gallery, but i want to set 3 items in the list, not more than that ...

```
List<File> images = [];
File _moreImage;

final picker = ImagePicker();

Future getMoreImages() async {
final pickedImage = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
setState(() {
  if (pickedImage != null) {
    _moreImage = File(pickedImage.path);
    images.add(_moreImage);
  } else {
    print('No images selected.');
  }
});
```

}

Comment: `List` class has `length` property - use it to check if you can `add()` new item or not

Comment: if (pickedImage != null && images.length <= 3) {
        _moreImage = File(pickedImage.path);
        images.add(_moreImage);
      } ,,, i am checking this.. still adding more than 3

Comment: `images.length < 3`

Answer (score 2):

You could change the code like this:

```
if (pickedImage != null && images.length < 3) {
    _moreImage = File(pickedImage.path);
    images.add(_moreImage);
  } else {
    print('No images selected (or no more than 3).');
  }
```

Comment: If this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.